# How do you select specific data from a column returned by a simple select statement?

Tags: sql

I have run a select statement in sql and the data has returned in the specific column as for example

Select reference from referencetable

JOEDOW12345678111111

What I require is to select DOW12345678 from the column.   The field is always going to be 20 characters long. It will always begin with JOE and end with 111111  so basically I just need to return the 11 characters after JOE which will always be 11 long. This is a reference that is all I require

So when doing a select how do I just select specific data from that column. In my case the reference which is in the middle of the data returned by the select statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What database server?

Comment: Please specify what your SQL software is. Implementations have varying features.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is going to be specific length you can directly use substring method. Fetching 11 chars from 4th should do what you want. This is how it would be done in MySQL:

```
select substr(reference, 4, 11) from referencetable;
```

Answer (score 1):

The function to use depends on the database:

MySQL, Oracle, Postgresql

```
select substr(reference,4,11) from referencetable
```

Microsoft SQL Server

```
select substring(reference,4,11) from referencetable
```

Microsoft Access

```
select mid(reference,4,11) from referencetable
```